# How to convert varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, varchar

I have a varchar column header (Prod_time) in the [YYYYmmdd hhmmss] format that I am trying to convert to datetime. I need to be able to pull data from a certain number of days, and I would like to be able to convert the varchar to datetime to facilitate this.

Is there a way to convert varchar to datetime? No special formatting of the datetime needed, only a data type conversion.

Comment: Why oh why are you storing datetime information in a varchar column in the first place? This has to be the single most abused datatype decision.

Comment: Believe me, if I could have it my way, we would not be storing date/time data in a varchar column! It makes working with the data that much more difficult and necessitates extra lines and manipulation. But at the company I work for, Managerial politics & security etc etc get in the way of preventing unnecessary nuisances like this =/

Answer (score 3):

You need to force a couple characters in here so that the convert function knows how to deal with this. We can use STUFF for this pretty easily. This works given the provided string format.

```
declare @SomeChar varchar(20) = '20170216 100903'

select CONVERT(datetime, STUFF(STUFF(@SomeChar, 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':'))
```

If at all possible you should consider converting the datatype to a datetime. It eliminates this kind of hassle and also prevents invalid values.