# How to convert varchar to datetime conver

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want to convert 20170426140000  to 2017-04-26 14:00:00

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert varchar to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277746/how-to-convert-varchar-to-datetime)

Comment: Conversion functions from string to datetime are different in the various DBMS. Which are you using? Then, do you get the string from a user or a column or is this a literal in a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve the above result with Help of `Substring` & `Stuff` function as below :-

```
DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DATA = '20170426140000';

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@DATA, 1, 4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@DATA, 5, 2)+'-'+SUBSTRING(@DATA, 7, 2)+' '+STUFF(STUFF(SUBSTRING(@DATA, 9, LEN(@data)), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'));
```

**Result :**

```
2017-04-26 14:00:00.000
```

Note : The above is for `SQL Server`

Comment: This looks far from Standard SQL. You seem to know which DBMS the OP is using. How come? And which is it?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner O/P is for SQL Server which was earlier mentioned.

Comment: No. Someone posted an answer for Oracle and when they were told that we don't know yet whether this request is for Oracle, they titled their (defective) Oracle query with SQL Server, before finally deleting the answer. We still don't know which DBMS the request is about.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner there was two answered provided the first one has the SQL Server comment posted by Question asker.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yogesh Sharma is right, OP commented, under an already deleted answer, that he uses sql server. But the tag is still missing.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

**In SQL Server**

```
DECLARE @InputText varchar(15)='20170426140000',@DateValue varchar(8),@FormattedDate varchar(50)
       SET @DateValue=LEFT(@InputText,8)
SELECT @FormattedDate =
convert(varchar(10), convert(datetime, @DateValue), 21)
+ ' ' + substring(@InputText, 9, 2)
+ ':' + substring(@InputText, 11, 2)
+ ':' + substring(@InputText, 13, 2)
SELECT @InputText AS Input,@FormattedDate AS FormattedDate
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (SQL-Server 2012+):

```
DECLARE @strDateTime varchar(14) = '20170426140000'

SELECT CONVERT(datetime,
               FORMAT(CONVERT(bigint, @strDateTime),
                      '####-##-## ##:##:##'),
               120)
```

If you only want to output the string and don't convert to datetime:

```
DECLARE @strDateTime varchar(14) = '20170426140000'

SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(bigint, @strDateTime),
              '####-##-## ##:##:##')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3b5b/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it like the below statement.

```
SELECT FORMAT(20170426140000,'0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```